# d3.js unit test for d3 event handlers

Tags: d3.js

:) I want to add unit test covering `brushHandler`, which is method of React Component for Brush part of my d3 graph.

Got stuck with solution how to fire D3BrushEvent correctly in unit tests...

Maybe someone has experience with testing handlers for d3 events?

```
    const area = selection.append('g')
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');

    const brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on('end', (event) => {
        if (event.selection) {
          const d1 = scale.invert(event.selection[0]);
          const d2 = scale.invert(event.selection[1]);
          brushHandler([d1, d2]);
          area.select<SVGGElement>('.brush').remove();
        }
      });

    area
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'brush')
      .call(brush);
```